# How to call webmethod in Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I want to call a web method in asp.net c# application using the following code

**Jquery:**

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'AddToCart.aspx/AddTo_Cart',
    type: "POST",
    data: "{'quantity' : " + total_qty + ",'itemId':" + itemId + "}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function () {
                  alert("Start!!! ");
               },
    success: function (data) {
                 alert("a");
              },
    failure: function (msg) { alert("Sorry!!! "); }
    });
```

**C# Code:**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string AddTo_Cart(int quantity, int itemId)
{
    SpiritsShared.ShoppingCart.AddItem(itemId, quantity);      
    return "Add";
}
```

But it always call page_load. How can i fix it?

Comment: From where are you making that ajax call?

Comment: very odd. whose page_load is called? AddToCart.aspx?

Comment: Yes,call AddToCart.aspx/Page_load

Answer (score 18):

There are quite a few elements of the `$.Ajax()` that can cause issues if they are not defined correctly. I would suggest rewritting your javascript in its most basic form, you will most likely find that it works fine.

Script example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Default.aspx/TestMethod',
    data: '{message: "HAI" }',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});
```

WebMethod example:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string TestMethod(string message)
{
     return "The message" + message;
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent starting point. Since this example works, you can then change it little by little to what you need and see at what point something goes wrong and then you know exactly what the issue is.

Answer (score 8):

This is a bit late, but I just stumbled on this problem, trying to resolve my own problem of this kind. I then realized that I had this line in the ajax post wrong:

```
data: "{'quantity' : " + total_qty + ",'itemId':" + itemId + "}",
```

It should be:

```
data: "{quantity : '" + total_qty + "',itemId: '" + itemId + "'}",
```

As well as the WebMethod to:

```
public static string AddTo_Cart(string quantity, string itemId)
```

And this resolved my problem.

Hope it may be of help to someone else as well.

Answer (score 2):

Necro'ing this Question ;)

You need to change the data being sent as Stringified JSON, that way you can modularize the Ajax call into a single supportable function.

### First Step: Extract data construction

```
/***
 * This helper is used to call WebMethods from the page WebMethods.aspx
 * 
 * @method - String value; the name of the Web Method to execute
 * @data - JSON Object; the JSON structure data to pass, it will be Stringified
 *      before sending
 * @beforeSend - Function(xhr, sett)
 * @success - Function(data, status, xhr)
 * @error - Function(xhr, status, err)
 */
function AddToCartAjax(method, data, beforeSend, success, error) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'AddToCart.aspx/', + method,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        beforeSend: beforeSend,
        success: success,
        error: error
    })
}
```

### Second Step: Generalize WebMethod

```
[WebMethod]
public static string AddTo_Cart ( object items ) {
    var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = js.ConvertToType<Dictionary<string , int>>( items );

    SpiritsShared.ShoppingCart.AddItem(json["itemId"], json["quantity"]);      
    return "Add";
}
```

### Third Step: Call it where you need it

This can be called just about anywhere, JS-file, HTML-file, or Server-side construction.

```
var items = { "quantity": total_qty, "itemId": itemId };

AddToCartAjax("AddTo_Cart", items,
    function (xhr, sett) {  // @beforeSend
        alert("Start!!!");
    }, function (data, status, xhr) {   // @success
        alert("a");
    }, function(xhr, status, err){  // @error
        alert("Sorry!!!");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem here is that your method expects int values while you are passing string from ajax call. Try to change it to string and parse inside the webmethod if necessary :

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string AddTo_Cart(string quantity, string itemId)
{
    //parse parameters here
    SpiritsShared.ShoppingCart.AddItem(itemId, quantity);      
    return "Add";
}
```

*Edit* : or Pass int parameters from ajax call.

Comment: it should be possible to pass directly int values from the ajax call?

Comment: @AlessioCavaleri unless you explicitly convert to int before passing then yes, otherwise it would expect string values...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why that isn't working, It works fine on my test.  But here is an alternative technique that might help.

Instead of calling the method in the AJAX url, just use the page .aspx url, and add the method as a parameter in the data object.  Then when it calls page_load, your data will be in the Request.Form variable.

**jQuery**

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'AddToCart.aspx',
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        method: 'AddTo_Cart', quantity: total_qty, itemId: itemId
    },
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function () {
        alert("Start!!! ");
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert("a");
    },
    failure: function (msg) { alert("Sorry!!! "); }
});
```

**C# Page Load:**

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    if (Request.Form["method"] == "AddTo_Cart")
    {
        int q, id;
        int.TryParse(Request.Form["quantity"], out q);
        int.TryParse(Request.Form["itemId"], out id);
        AddTo_Cart(q,id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this work around will allow your code to work, it is terrible practice and your future self will no doubt be disappointed in you when you have to maintain this tragic mess

Comment: I added a downvote as this is a hacky work around that I don't think will help people in the same situation as the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at `[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]`, add `[WebMethod(EnableSession = false)]` and you could get rid of page life cycle, by default EnableSession is true in Page and making page to come in life though life cycle events..

Please refer below page for more details 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.enablesessionstate.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you need to `JSON.stringify` the `data parameter` before sending it.

Answer (score -1):

Here is your answer.
use

```
                   jquery.json-2.2.min.js 
                      and
                   jquery-1.8.3.min.js
```

Javascript :

```
function CallAddToCart(eitemId, equantity) {
   var itemId = Number(eitemId);
   var quantity = equantity;
   var dataValue = "{itemId:'" + itemId+ "', quantity :'"+ quantity "'}" ;
    $.ajax({
           url: "AddToCart.aspx/AddTo_Cart",
           type: "POST",
           dataType: "json",
           data: dataValue,
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           success: function (msg) {
                alert("Success");
           },
           error: function () { alert(arguments[2]); }      
        });
 }
```

and your C# web method should be

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string AddTo_Cart(int itemId, string quantity)
{
   SpiritsShared.ShoppingCart.AddItem(itemId, quantity);      
  return "Item Added Successfully";
}
```

From any of the button `click` or any other html control `event` you can call to the `javascript` method with the parameter which in turn calls to the `webmethod` to get the value in `json` format.