# Advice on using Javascript in C# environment

Tags: c#, javascript, webforms

I need something with similar functionality to the NumericUpDown tool of Windows Forms, and I've been informed that there is a javascript function of this nature. All the guides I can find from a google search seem to cover print functions and other features, that I'm not sure how to adapt.

How would I incorporate the javascript function into my web form and pass it's value reliably to the corresponding c# method?

Please forgive me if this is a silly question, I'm comparatively new to programming in general.

Comment: Depending on the browsers you target, there is an [`<input type=number>`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number) that's a built-in "up/down" input.

Comment: You can use some jquery plugin for numeric updown, and then use jquery ajax request to submit values to C# function.

Comment: @HansKesting this should work OK, I'm in a corporate environment where everyone has at least IE9. How would I implement this in a C# webform?

Comment: IE9 doesn't support it, IE10/11 don't show the up/down buttons. Apart from that, you could use `<input type=number runat=server>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Spinner](http://jqueryui.com/spinner/) plugin for JQuery.

From the client side using Jquery's [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method you can pass the variables to backend.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110170/how-to-call-webmethod-in-asp-net-c-sharp) might help calling web methods via Ajax.

Comment: How would I implement this in C#? is it a question of just placing it in the aspx page that I'm working in, and surrounding it with <script></script>?

Comment: From the client side you can get the values using javascript. Then pass these values to a web method that is written in C#. In short, it would be better to place client side scripts in ASPX page.