# How to call code behind method between script tag?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to give language choice to my web site.I'm working in Asp.net and using `<a>` tag.I have to use JavaScript because, `onclick` event doesn't see code behind methods.But I don't know how call code behind method in script tag.Does anyone know about this?Please advice..

My code behind method:

```
protected void ConvertToEN(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["Lang"];
            if (cookie == null) cookie = new HttpCookie("Lang");
            cookie.Value = "en-US";
            Response.SetCookie(cookie);
            Response.Redirect("First_Page.aspx");
        }
```

And these are `<a>` tags:

```
    <ul>
       <li><a id="translaterAZ">AZ</a></li>
       <li><a id="translaterRU">RU</a></li>
       <li><a id="translaterEN">EN</a></li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: use Webmethods for this https://stackoverflow.com/a/25262178/795683

Answer (score 0):

You could use a LinkButton.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="MyLinkButton" runat="server" OnClick="ConvertToEN">EN</asp:LinkButton>
```

C#

```
protected void ConvertToEN(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["Lang"];
    if (cookie == null) cookie = new HttpCookie("Lang");
    cookie.Value = "en-US";
    Response.SetCookie(cookie);
    Response.Redirect("First_Page.aspx");
}
```